# Does MSBuild has an OnImport callback or something similar to detect importing?

Tags: msbuild

The intention in the title sounds more complex as it is

I have a script which looks like that:

```
<Import Project="MSBuild/Backend.msbuild.xml" />

<PropertyGroup>
        <Data>SomeData</Data>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and I simply want to detect whether the `Import` statement is before or after the `PropertyGroup` because the Backend script looks like

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <BasedOnData>$(Data)/magic.exe</BasedOnData>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If the `Import` statement comes first, `BasedOnData` just looks like `/magic.exe` which is wrong. If the `Import` comes last, everything is fine.

I tried to check the `Data` Property in a Target in `Backend` but at target-calling-time `Data` is already defined.
Resulting in

`Data=SomeData`

but

`BasedOnData=/magic.exe`

I could create an `Error` condition based whether `$(BasedOnData)== '/magic.exe'` but this is error prone as it relies on `Data` and `BasedOnData`s value.

Having an `Error` condition in `PropertyGroup` does not work.

Any smarter solution to this known?

Should I fallback to `CreateProperty` in the first target so I am agnostic of the position of the `Import` statement? (This gets much more verbose and is not that easy to read than a plain nice `PropertyGroup`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution of MSBuild targets happens in separate pass, after all properties in property groups have been evaluated. So what you are observing is designed behavior.

To make import order checking in your case, the following should do the trick. Inside your Backend.msbuild.xml file add this:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Data_Copy>$(Data)</Data_Copy>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

This just makes a copy of whatever $(Data) value was at the time. Then in either same imported file or in any other target, add this `<Error>` task:

```
    <Error Text="Import has to be specified after `Data` is defined" Condition="'$(Data_Copy)' == ''" />
```

This will break the build if Backend.msbuild.xml was imported before `$(Data)` is defined.